# How to handle multiple uploads in Hapi.js

Tags: bash, curl, file-upload, hapi.js

The following index.js works fine when multiple uploads are submitted
 with:

```
curl http://localhost:4000/upload -F 'files=@data/file1.txt' -F
'files=@data/file2.txt'
```

But it fails if only one file is submitted:

```
curl http://localhost:4000/upload -F 'files=@data/file1.txt'
```

because hapi is expecting `files` to be an array.

It doesn't work either if I use `files[]` instead, that is

```
curl http://localhost:4000/upload -F 'files[]=@data/file1.txt'
```

I can work around the problem by checking in `index.js` if `files` is an array or not, if not I'll just wrap it with **[files]** so the remaining code won't break but I feel the solution is not that elegant. Is this a limitation/bug in hapi.js file upload handling?

```
/* index.js */
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const server = new Hapi.Server()
server.connection({
    port:4000
})

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        config: {
            payload: {
                output: 'stream',
                parse: true,
                allow: 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        },
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            const p = request.payload, files = p.files
            if(files) {
                console.log(`${files.length} files`)
                files.forEach(function(file) {
                    // do something with file here
                })
            }
            return reply({result: 'ok'})
        }
    }
]

server.route(routes)

server.start(function() {
    console.log(`server started at ${server.info.uri}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, Hapi won't be able to tell whether the `files` element is an array, unless it can infer it from multiple uses in a request.

You should be able to tell Hapi how to interpret it explicitly by adding [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#readme) payload validation. Something like:

```
config: {
    payload: {
        output: 'stream',
        parse: true,
        allow: 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    validate: {
        payload: Joi.object({
            files: Joi.array().single()
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: Didn't know about single(), great use case. I've tested with your suggestion, it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered it's actually quite easy to make sure files is always an array by using this technique:

```
const p = request.payload, files = [].concat(p.files)
```